# Firefox not repainting when scrollable box sits on top of element with opacity and height

Tags: javascript, firefox, dom

This is probably the most bizarre thing I've encountered in my years of website coding, so I thought I would run it by some people who are way smarter than me to try to explain why this is happening. If there's no explanation, I'm probably going to submit it as a bug report. It took me forever to actually suss out the cause of the problem.

The following behavior I can only produce in Firefox (version 15, currently, and maybe some others). No problem exists in Internet Explorer, Chrome, or Safari. It's so difficult to explain that I just created a demonstration here: http://sandbox.uatu.net/dom-changes.php

The general idea is that under a very specific set of conditions, DOM changes are getting held up by Firefox when a scrollable box is scrolled, whether the scrolling is done by the user or is automated by a script. Here's the set-up:

```
<div id="superContainer">
   <div id="subContainer">
       <div id="mainPage">
           scrollable box in here
       </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Important attributes:

- ## superContainer has height and width dimensions
- ## subContainer has a height dimension
- ## subContainer has an opacity setting less than 1
- ## subContainer has a background color
- ## mainPage has a position attribute of absolute

Anyway, what you'll see if you visit that demo page is that attempting to scroll the box freezes up all page animations. You can actually watch some of these elements in Firebug and see that the properties are changing in real time, but Firefox is just refusing to repaint anything on the page.

If you toggle any of these attributes into an off position, everything is fine. It's just this particular combination of settings that seems to produce the problem.

Does anybody have any thoughts as to why? I can't tell you how crazy this drove me--I was basically troubleshooting it all weekend, totally refactoring my code on the site where I discovered it.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to me that the opacity + position absolute are the culprits here, read the w3 specs on transparency to understand how engines render and threat opacity.

http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-color/#transparency

> Since an element with opacity less than 1 is composited from a single
>   offscreen image, content outside of it cannot be layered in z-order
>   between pieces of content inside of it. For the same reason,
>   implementations must create a new stacking context for any element
>   with opacity less than 1. If an element with opacity less than 1 is
>   not positioned, implementations must paint the layer it creates,
>   within its parent stacking context, at the same stacking order that
>   would be used if it were a positioned element with ‘z-index: 0’ and
>   ‘opacity: 1’. If an element with opacity less than 1 is positioned,
>   the ‘z-index’ property applies as described in [[CSS21]](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-color/#CSS21), except that
>   ‘auto’ is treated as ‘0’ since a new stacking context is always
>   created. See [section 9.9](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#layers) and [Appendix E](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/zindex.html) of [[CSS21]](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-color/#CSS21) for more
>   information on stacking contexts. The rules in this paragraph do not
>   apply to SVG elements, since SVG has its own [rendering model](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/render.html) ([[SVG11]](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-color/#SVG11),
>   Chapter 3).

If you remove position: absolute from #mainPage you will notice the bug to be gone, you might want to file the bug anyway and think of a plan B for your implementation.

Comment: Thanks. I think that explains it. I did find an alternative: using a PNG with transparency in place of setting the opacity on the subContainer. Works fine that way. I'm glad to know what the problem was, though.

Comment: the png should be a more conscious decision performance wise, this is a great find by the way